# "Broken" mesh and particles extremely big - Mantaflow fluid simulation

Tags: mesh, particles, fluid-simulation

I was searching for some new ideas and I found this beer pint, so I thought to use it for a mantaflow simulation of a beer. So I did the basic actions of creating domain, collision and inflow object, but then when I start the simulation I noticed that the mesh is like broken, it's like it has holes since the fluid leaks out from the sides. So I verified if the mesh was "okay" and I couldn't find any holes. Here is some footage:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to increase the surface thickness but from 0.0 to 0.5 is pointless since some particles leak out and from 0.5 to 1 it's too thick, since you can see the fluid not even touching the surface of the glass.

Does someone of you experienced this and know how to fix this is?

EDIT-1:
I scaled everything to a real world scale, so now the model is exactly 0.3 meters tall, like the real one. The leak of particles is partially resolved, but now the particles are as big as the pint!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particle Properties -> Click on Liquid -> Viewport Display -> Size 1mm or something smaller

As seen on: https://blenderartists.org/t/is-there-such-a-thing-as-too-small-of-a-scale-for-mantaflow-flip-fluids-particles-too-big/1208348